# .htaccess not working as expected in sub-folder

Tags: .htaccess

I have this rewrite rule placed in /dashboard/.htaccess [dashboard is actually a folder]:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?mode=$1 [L]
```

My structure is index.php?mode=support, even though, $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] outputs this:

```
mode=index.php

Example: site.com/dashboard/index.php?mode=support should be site.com/dashboard/support
```

So , how can I make it parse the param value, and not the file itself.

Comment: As far as I know .htaccess should be in root folder

Comment: @Ani .htaccess can be in any folder

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve it while doing more research on regular expressions.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ index.php?mode=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Thi solved my problem, preferred plus instead asterisk because it tells the engine to repeat it zero or more times. (when i'm on index.php , query string is empty as needed)

Answer (score 0):

Your rule is matching anything that starts with not a slash and doesnt contain a slash anywhere when your actual path is

```
/dashboard/support
```

to get the folder you actually want you need a base on there like this

```
RewriteBase /dashboard/
```

If that is placed above the rule, Then your redirect should be ok

Comment: I placed this above the rule, the result is the same. I've used generateit.net/mod-rewrite/ to get the rewrite rule from site.com/dashboard/index.php?mode=news to site.com/dashboard/news but it still has the same effect. query string $1 still gets 'index.php' as value.